# Angular update formcontrol with javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, angular-reactive-forms

We have got an Angular Application with a view

```html
<input [formControl]="fc" (keyup)="change($event)" id="test">
check if it worked: {{ fc.value }}
```

and the component

```js
public fc = new FormControl('nothing here');
public change(event): void {
    console.log('changed', event);
}
```

**How can I change the input with javascript to simulate a *real* user input?**

The solution has to work with IE11.

We can change the value with js:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('test');
el.value = 'success';
```

The value changes but the `change`-method is not being called and the formControl.value is not being updated.

How can I achieve this?

I cannot do anything inside of the component code as its a separate environment that executes this code. I already tried with `el.dispatchEvent(someEvent)` after the value change. Where someEvent was new Event / new KeyboardEvent with `keyup`, `keydown`, `change`, and also gave it objects like `{key: 's'}` ... and nothing worked so far. Also tried with `el.focus()` and `el.blur()` and some other things.

The assumption is that this has to do with `changeDetection` and that the fc doesn't get updated since `setValue` nor `patchValue` get called.

There must be something like this:

```js
el.value = 'success';
angular.pleaseDoCorrespondingStuff();
```

Any Ideas?

*Please note that for simplifying the example the (keyup) is just an example here, could be anything. In reality we wrap the angular material datepicker in the template and have a (dateChange)-event here.*

Answer (score 1):

<s>Please check your code, in the change event, you didn't change the value. I have created a sample on my side using the following code, it seems that everything works well, I could get the log and the data update</s>

Code in the component.ts:

```
  onSearchChange(searchValue : string ) {  
    console.log(searchValue);
    this.name = searchValue;
  }
```

Code in component.html :

```
<input type="text" id="txtinput" class="form-control" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)"><br/>
<span>{{ name}}</span>
```

I have created a sample using your code, When I using the following code to send keys, it will trigger the input event and get the log:

```
            var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
            {
                InitialBrowserUrl = URL,
                IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,                   
            };


            var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);
            driver.Navigate();
            var text = driver.FindElementById("test");
            text.SendKeys("aa");

            text.SendKeys("bb");
```

Comment: Hi Lv, thank you for the answer. The onSearchChange however should not set a value but is used in a different way to emit and event upon which we react to and do other stuff. I didnt write everything but a console.log to show that I want to see that the method got called. Whatever we tried, SendKeys typed something, just what el.value = xyz does. BUT, the Angular FormControl doesnt change the value nor does the method get called with this solution. I cannot use (input) since we don't control the Angular Material naming.

Comment: I notice that your question was modified, whether you are still using the IE selenium webdriver? If still using this method, I have also created a sample to test your code and using the sendkeys method to simulate a real user input, the code works well on my side. the screenshot [as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZK3P.gif).

Comment: Thank you @zhi-lv does this work in IE11? I changed the answer because I'd like to know how to trigger that in Angular in general - not necessarily selenium. Selenium is just the circumstance here and yes, would make things better here, however I'd prefer a plain JS solution to be able to understand what is going on.

Comment: Yes, it works in IE 11, you could check the screenshot in the previous comment, it is using IE browser.